# Splitting up Shacharis between two Chiyuvim

Tags: minhag, tefilla, sources-mekorot, chazzan-prayer-leader

I have Davened in a few Shuls where they have split up Shacharis between two Chiyuvim. (One Davens until Ashrei after Tachanun / One davens from Ashrei until the end.) What is the source for doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Beur Halacha* 132](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&pgnum=28) discusses drawing lots to determine who leads the service and then adds (in my own loose translation):

> … and all this is when they can't both lead the service; if they can, and both are acceptable to the congregation, then let them draw lots [only] to determine who leads until "*Ashre–Uva l'tziyon*" and who leads from there on.

Comment: A note. Normally the shaliach tzibbur need not take three steps backward after his repetition of the Amidah; the three steps after the Kaddish Tiskabel are sufficient. But when the shaliach tzibbur(1) will not say Kaddish Tiskabel as here when the davenning is split, he **will** need to take the three steps back.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66455