# Is it permissible to switch the chazzan in the middle of shacharit on a weekday?

Tags: halacha, chazzan-prayer-leader, shacharis-morning-prayer, minyan

In [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 55:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.55.3?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all), the Rama states that if there was a minyan for the beginning of Shmoneh Esrei and some left, the chazzan can say up to (and including) Kaddish Shalem (after Uva Letziyon). This is because the whole thing is connected to Shmoneh Esrei.

On days that have a full minyan with no one leaving in the middle, I have sometimes seen the chazzan sit down after Torah reading and someone else take his place.

Is this allowed [*l'chatchila*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5151)? As i mentioned above, it seems that this whole section, from Shmoneh Esrei through Kaddish is connected. Therefore, it seems that the chazzan shouldn't stop in the middle.

Comment: what does the first paragraph have to do with the second? You're implication is that "splitting" the section is disallowed, but you provide no basis for that. On the contrary, we specifically discuss replacing a chazzan mid shmoneh esrei! If that's okay, then swapping out afterwards is certainly allowed. The only question is under what circumstances.

Comment: Your question I understand to be can one have another chazan for 'ashrei uvo lzion'. I seem to remember that although commonly done it is only allowed if there are two aveilim or chiyuvim.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Yes, i imply that from my own reasoning -- splitting a single section seems wrong. If you can disprove that, by all means, do so!

Comment: Simple. If the chazzan for any reason cannot complete the repetition, we appoint another in his stead. I've just disproved the supposition that you cannot split because we already have laws saying that you DO split in some circumstances.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky So we have a case *b'dieved*. What about *l'chatchila* switching the chazzan? That's more my case. I'll edit that in.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your supposition is unjustified because it already contradicts established law. And, as @cham notes, we only engage in this practice (generally) when there is a need for two individuals to lead - a suboptimal case.

Comment: http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/print.asp?id=47399&kod=&modul=15&codeClient=58

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17626/759

Answer (score 6):

Seems that the answer is: **Yes, one may do so a priori**.

See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן כו - דיני קדיש יתום](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0048_L5):

> **סעיף יד**: מִי שֶׁיָּכוֹל וְרָאוּי לְהִתְפַּלֵּל לִפְנֵי הַתֵּבָה, יִתְפַּלֵּל, וּמוֹעִיל יוֹתֵר מִקַּדִּישׁ יָתוֹם, שֶׁלֹּא נִתְקַן אֶלָּא לַקְטַנִּים. **וּמִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְהִתְפַּלֵּל כָּל הַתְּפִלָּה, יִתְפַּלֵּל מִן אַשְׁרֵי וּבָא לְצִיּוֹן וּלְהַלָּן**. וּמִי שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ זְכוּת יוֹתֵר בְּקַדִּישִׁים, כְּגוֹן, בֶּן ז' וְל', יֵשׁ לוֹ גַּם כֵּן זְכוּת יוֹתֵר בְּעִנְיַן הַתְּפִלָּה. נוֹהֲגִין שֶׁאֵין אָבֵל מִתְפַּלֵּל לִפְנֵי הַתֵּבָה בַּשַׁבָּת וְיוֹם טוֹב. אַךְ אִם גַּם קֹדֶם הָאֲבֵלוּת, הָיָה דַּרְכּוֹ לְהִתְפַּלֵּל בַּשַׁבָּת וְיוֹם טוֹב, גַּם בִּזְמַן הָאֲבֵלוּת יִתְפַּלֵּל. (שַעֲרֵי תְּשׁוּבָה בְֹּשֵם תְֹּשוּבַת מֵאִיר נְתִיבִים סִימָן פ', וְעַיֵּן לְקַמָּן סִימָן קכ"ח סָעִיף ח') ‏
>
> :**סעיף טו**:  שְׁנַיִם שֶׁשָּׁוִים בְּדִין קַדִּישׁ, וּשְׁנֵיהֶם יְכוֹלִים לְהִתְפַּלֵּל לִפְנֵי הַתֵּבָה, וּמְרֻצִּים בְּשָׁוֶה לַקָּהָל, יַטִילוּ גּוֹרָל, **שֶׁהָאֶחָד יִתְפַּלֵּל עַד אַשְׁרֵי וּבָא לְצִיּוֹן, וְהַשֵּׁנִי יִתְפַּלֵּל אַשְׁרֵי וּבָא לְצִיּוֹן**. וְאִם אֶחָד אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְהִתְפַּלֵּל לִפְנֵי הַתֵּבָה, אוֹ שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְרֻצֶּה לַקָּהָל, וְהִתְפַּלֵּל הַשֵּׁנִי, לֹא הִפְסִיד זֶה שֶׁהִתְפַּלֵּל זְכוּתוֹ בַּקַדִּישִׁים, וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם יֵשׁ לוֹ לְוַתֵּר, לְהַנִּיחַ הַקַּדִּישׁ לְמִי שֶׁלֹּא הִתְפַּלֵּל, וּמִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן לִקְטַנִּים. ‏

From סעיף טו it seems it's perfectly OK to switch a Chazzan at אַשְׁרֵי - and is the preferred method when 2 people have equal stakes. Even though one may think that a better solution would be that they alternate days, the Halcha is that they switch at אַשְׁרֵי.